# Debugging Issue in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, how to debug only a part of the code (Not from the starting).

In the below code, the debugging is getting stuck at LINE 1 forever, no matter how many times I press F6 .

I want to skip the first FOR loop , and start debugging from LINE 2.

NOTE : LINE 1 runs a query which takes about 20 mins time. I already ran once . Can we use the previous output only, instead of the query running again.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Future<ResultSet> f1; 
        Future<ResultSet> f2;
for(int i=0;i<futures.size();i++){
            feed_rs.add(futures.get(i).get()); //  <===  LINE 1
}

for(int i=0;i<feed_rs.size();i++){
  // More code   // <===  LINE 2

}
```

Comment: I'd start off by learning [how to debug stuff in Eclipse,](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/analyzing_debugger_results.htm) with particular focus on how to set a breakpoint.  In this case, I'd remark out the 20 minute query, so it doesn't run.  You would have to paste previous results in a temporary variable somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the breakpoint to hold only under specific conditions.

If i understand you correctly you like to break when

```
feed_rf.isEmpty() == false
```

Place this line in the conditions of the breakpoint in LINE1.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint directly *only* on Line 2 and press F8.